# Synchronize zoom level between 3 graphs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have 3 graph components on my page. They draw a line graph from, let's say 10 measurments. Each graph can be zoomed in/out by scroll wheel. Chart component expose an event function property `onZoom`, so if I bind a handler to it with `console.log` for example, I can see the output in console when any zooming occurs, no problem. The value outputed in console represents an array of `[from, to]` values representing from what x to what x now graph have to be displayed (a **domain**).

I want to set the same zoom levels on other 2 graphs. In order to do it graph component must be created with `ref` property accessed by reference later to call `.zoom()` passing **domain**, so in result I need to call something like `this.refs.myChart.zoom(domain)` to set a new zoom.

I am using `redux` and when zooming changes I dispach a "ZOOM" event, that then changes store, and that store value is binded to `zoomDomain` prop in each of 3 graphs, and I can see that each of the graph now have new zoom level (domain) set properly as a property.

Now I cannot understand how and where do I need to call `refs.myChart.zoom(this.props.zoomDomain)` in order to update/set zoom levels on other charts?

If I do it in `render()`, I will get an error that I should not do anything in `render()` that changes state, so how can I do it then?

**P.S.** if it matters, the lib that I use for graphs is [react-c3js](https://github.com/bcbcarl/react-c3js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you correctly you have a Base component. In that component's render method you have 3 charts.

Once the zoom is changed, you can handle it and update the rest charts.

**Here is an example code if you have a slider (that manipulates the zoom)**:

```
class Base extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            from: 0,
            to: 1
        };
    }

    handleChange(from, to) {
        this.refs.chartOne.zoom(nextProps.from, nextProps.to);
        this.refs.chartTwo.zoom(nextProps.from, nextProps.to);
        this.refs.chartThree.zoom(nextProps.from, nextProps.to);

        this.setState({ from, to });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Chart ref="chartOne" />
                <Chart ref="chartTwo" />
                <Chart ref="chartThree" />

                <Slider onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Here is an example code if your charts support `zoom` property**:

```
class Base extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            zoom: {
                from: 0,
                to: 1
            }
        };
    }

    handleChange(from, to) {
        this.setState({ zoom: {from, to} });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Chart zoom={this.state.zoom} />
                <Chart zoom={this.state.zoom} />
                <Chart zoom={this.state.zoom} />

                <Slider onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: not entirely. My new zoom levels comes from one of the chart, not from slider on base component. But I got the idea, I will try it out.

Comment: BTW `componentWillReceiveProps` is unnecessary, because it's not triggered on a state update. I changed my code example. So independatly from where the zoom change occurs (from a <Slider /> or <Chart /> component) - you can handle it via `onChange` props and in the handler method you can update all the charts (via refs).

BTW there is another aproach too. `react-c3js` components have `zoom` property. So handling the zoom change (as the above example) + <Chart zoom={this.state.zoom} /> may be enough.

If you need support - feel free to ask.

Comment: the problem is that charts to not support zoom as a property and all the pain is due to that. Zoom property can define callbacks, but you cannot pass zoom domain to it, unfortunately. The only way to change the zoom is to call a method `.zoom(domain)`

Comment: Alright. What about my first code example then (with `refs`)?

Comment: it works, but kind of interesting: it applies zoom level to other graphs, but it seems that it is not like the current zoom level, but previous. For example initial domain is [0,100]. So if I zoom in for the first time, current graph will have zoom level like [10,90], others - [0, 100]. If I zoom again on the same graph, this graph will have [20,80] and others will have [10,90].

Comment: Create JSFiddle and will support you here. :)

Comment: I tried, but there's a problem to add react-c3js to it https://jsfiddle.net/L9rkghmo/4/

Comment: Okay. Please try the following Fiddle as the base one: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/15384/

Comment: @kaytrance I've fixed your fiddle. You have to select **1.7** as JavaScript version and **No wrap in head** as Load type. https://jsfiddle.net/jordan_enev/L9rkghmo/5/